# DNS A record to external wordpress site, what do I set the "site url" to

Tags: wordpress, dns, a-records

Let's say I have a Wordpress site on `example-domain.com` and I want to host that website on another server that has the domain `exampledomain.com` (without the dash)?

`example-domain.com` remains the host for email and another application but I just want to set the A and AAAA records to point to the new host that has a copy of the Wordpress installation. What do I set the site url setting to when I want the url to remain the same and will both domain work?